# How can I a position a div with 3 font-awesome-icons so the website is responsive?

Tags: html, css

How can I a position a div with 3 font-awesome icons, one at the left, one in the middle, and one at the right with `position: absolute/relative` (so the design is responsive)?

If I do `position: absolute` on the div which wraps the icons they stack one on top of each other.

This is how I've done it. But I realized because of that `margin-top: 6vw` it will not be as responsive as the others where they move as I resize the browsers because of the `position: absolute` and percentages. So how should I do it?

```css
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 62%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 600px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#central-skills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-top: 15vw;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.trying {
    text-align: center;
}

#website ul {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#websites li:before {
    content: "\2714\0020";
}

#websites {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

.trying {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
}

.websites {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    bottom: 43%;
}

#websites {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    margin-left: 10rem;
}

#websites ul {
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

#websites li {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.list-adv {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: #77dff1;
}

.scratch {
    padding: 6rem 5.5rem 6rem 5.6rem;
}

.mobile-skills {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#icons {
    font-size: 10rem;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6vw;
}

.fa-html5 {
    float: left;
}

.fa-js-square {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.fa-css3-alt {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script defer src="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="central-skills">
            <div id="canvas">
                <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
                <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>
            </div>
            <div id="skills" style="display: none;">
                <h6 class="trying">Currently I consider myself familiar and comfortable with:</h6>
                <h6 class="mobile-skills">html CSS JavaScript jQuery Bootstrap Canvas</h6>
                <div id="icons">
                    <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-js-square"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="websites"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-adv 1">Responsive</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 2">Using a clean and easy to follow code</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 3">Clean and good-looking</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 4">Optimized for Search Engines (SEO)</li>
                        <li class="list-adv scratch">Coded from scratch (unless there is a need of a CMS)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Consider removing the inline `display: none` property preventing readers from viewing the issue in question, and include the external CDN library for FontAwesome so font icons can render as well.

Comment: I did right now.

Comment: not really, unfortunately - nothing is displayed.

Comment: `#skills` is still attributed to `display: none;`, the fontawesome file should reference a CSS source (you've included a javascript file) and the filepath should be *relative*, not *absolute*. Basically, the embedded code snippet should *work*; *demonstrate* and *reproduce* the issue described in the problem statement.

Comment: Johannes helped me. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: No problem, I was just trying to help you to improve the question itself. Glad you found the droid... err, answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox on the container div of those icons, using "justify-content: space-between`. This will place them left, center and right.

```
#icons {
    font-size: 10rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 6vw;
}
```

Comment: And how can I position the whole div with position: absolute without them getting stacked?

Comment: In this case you need to define a width for it, and `top` and `left` (or `right`) settings. And `position: relative` for the parent element to define it as the position anchor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me!